# Why are some names, like none vs. hidden and href vs. src so inconsistent in CSS and HTML?

Tags: html, css, naming, w3c

Hi, this is more a conceptual question. How did the W3C decide to use `hidden` vs. `none`? I'm asking  because I'm an ESL person (English as a second language). If I'm using `overflow: hidden`,  `overflow: none` could just as well be used. The same goes for `display: none` and `visibility: hidden`. Couldn't it just have been `display: none` and `visibility: none`, because what really make the difference is the properties `display` and `visibility` and not their value. This is more a request for an explanation. Similiar "weird" things happens for example:

```
<script src="file.js">
```

and

```
<link href="file.css">
```

Why are they different? I understand how all of this works technically, I'm just curious about how they decided the names of the attributes.

Thanks.

Comment: link and script both bring an external file to xhtml file but use different approaches href vs src..

Comment: We use `src` on **replaced** elements. `script` is a *replaced* element while `link` creates link between the referencing document and an external resource. Hence we use `href` for that.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

The reason these entities (elements, properties, attributes, etc.) are named different things is because they serve different purposes. Let's start from the top and go through your examples.

### Display vs. Visibiliy

```
display: none;
visibility: hidden;
```

As you can see from [the CSS 2.1 specification](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/propidx.html), the value `none` is used for many different properties to indicate that the property's visual aspect should not be shown. So if the property is `float`, `none` means the element isn't floating. For the property [`display`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#propdef-display), `none` means it's not displaying.

For [`visibility`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#propdef-visibility),  `hidden` is different, since it unlike `display`, doesn't affect element flow. The element's box will still be rendered, but it will be invisible. If you gave the value `none` to `visibility`, it would semantically mean the exact same thing as `display: none`, which it isn't.

### Overflow

```
overflow: hidden;
overflow: none;
```

These mean different things. `hidden` says that the content that overflows the size of the element will be clipped, while `none` says that there is no overflow control; in effect turning overflow off. `none` is not a valid value for [`overflow`](http://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visufx.html#propdef-overflow), but in this case, `visible` has the same effect.

### Src vs. href

```
<script src="file.js">
<link href="file.css">
```

The difference between `script` and `link` is that while a `script`'s main purpose is to embed (either inline, or through reference via the `src` attribute) a script inside the HTML document, the purpose of `link` is to refer to other URIs on the world wide web. The fact that you use `link` to refer to a CSS stylesheet is not very intuitive; a more intuitive solution might be:

```
<style src="file.css" />
```

I don't have the details on why the HTML Working Group chose to use `link` and not `style`, but from a little bit of digging, it seems that the `link` element was already present in [HTML 1.0](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/draft-ietf-iiir-html-01.txt) and [HTML 2.0](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html-spec/html-spec_5.html#SEC5.2.4) and that `style` wasn't introduced until [HTML 3.0](http://www.w3.org/MarkUp/html3/dochead.html).

As discussions around a style sheet language started as early as [in 1993](http://virtuelvis.com/archives/2005/01/css-history) (the same year HTML 1.0 was completed) and HTML 3.0 wasn't done until 1995, it makes sense that they found a way to embed stylesheets before the `style` element was invented.

Comment: That's a better answer than mine xD GJGJ

Comment: I beg to differ on the `<style src="file.css" />` thing though. If implemented that way, the processing of the page would pause until the CSS file is downloaded.

Comment: @apnerve, How is it different from today's solution with `<link href="file.css" />`?

Comment: @asbjornu `<link href="file.css" />` implementation is different as per the specs. The file gets downloaded in parallel and the processing of the page(HTML) is not paused. When using `href`, we are telling the *user-agent* (browser in this case) that *file.css* is a file that is **related** to the `html` document. If we use `src`, it's like telling the *user-agent* to download the file, dump the content of the file inside the tag and then proceed. That is the reason, `img`, `script` and `iframe` make the page load slower.

Comment: @apnerve, Sure, but since `<style src>` doesn't exist, it is (or at least was) entirely possible to specify that downloading the `src` should not halt page rendering. It's also incorrect that all `src`'s halt page rendering; `img` doesn't. First, a placeholder (with the size given in the `<img>` tag, if available) is rendered for every `img`, then the placeholder is replaced with every image file once they are downloaded.

Comment: @asbjornu : Thanks for the clarification. After so much thought I feel you are right. `<style src>` is more intuitive. I mistook it for `<link src>`